# Why could Voldemort freely harm Harry when he took Harry's blood for his own?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, lily-potter

In the graveyard in the Goblet of Fire, Voldemort was able to freely touch Harry without harm once he possessed Harry's blood (which contained Lily's sacrificial protection).

**Why?**

Voldemort was still Voldemort, he was still evil and malicious, even if the blood he possessed was not his own. Shouldn't Harry's blood have recognized that? What are the specific mechanics of the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Harry's blood contains the love from Lily's sacrifice. Even though Voldemort is so full of hatred he can't possess Harry who's full of love, the small amount of love that went into Voldemort through Harry's blood was enough for Voldemort to touch Harry.

> "Your mother died to save you. If there is one thing Voldemort cannot
> understand, it is love. He didn't realize that love as powerful as
> your mother's for you leaves its own mark. Not a scar, no visible
> sign... to have been loved so deeply, even though the person who loved
> us is gone, will give us some protection forever. It is in your very
> skin. Quirrell, full of hatred, greed, and ambition, sharing his soul
> with Voldemort, could not touch you for this reason. It was agony to
> touch a person marked by something so good."

The fact that Voldemort can't touch Harry and the fact that he can't kill Harry are to different things: Voldemort can't touch Harry because he is full of hatred and Harry is full of love, and he can't kill Harry because of the sacrifice protection on Harry. Voldemort basically put a bit of love inside him so he'll be able to touch Harry.

Comment: Yeah that makes a good amount of sense. Especially since JK Rowling explained in an interview that Voldemort unknowingly put a few 'drops of goodness' inside of him when he took Harry's blood when rebuilding his body. I guess that could tie into why he was able to touch Harry.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make sense. Quirrell burned because Harry touched him, but Voldemort in a cauldron with Harry's blood is no problem?

Comment: @RalfFriedl do you mind elaborating on that question further? I'm a little confused as to what you're specifically asking? Are you asking why Voldemort didn't burn in pain when he was developing his new body in Goblet of Fire and his frail little form was tossed into the cauldron?

Comment: Exactly. Quirrel burned when Harry touched him, because he had Voldemort inside his head. Harry's blood is added to the cauldron with Voldemort inside, but Harry's blood and the protection against Voldemort contained in that blood doesn't hurt Voldemort.